# How to define the name of a bash function to be a regex

Tags: bash, scripting, zsh, function

I've searched around and can't find an answer.

I want to define a function like this

```
function \d{2} () {
    echo $1_or_smth
}
```

Then if I say in my terminal

```
12
```

I want it to echo 12 back.

Comment: You're asking for defining a function with a variable name. I think this would cause more problems than being helpful. What about telling us what you actually want to achieve? Read http://xyproblem.info/ first before you continue. And please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I already said what i wanted to achieve: I want to type 12 into my terminal, and have it echo 12.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach will work for zsh:

```
preexec() {
  if [[ $1 = <-> ]]; then
    $1() {
      echo $0
      unfunction $0
    }                                                            
  fi
}
```

As noted in the comments on your question, you can't have a function with a variable name. What this does is use the `preexec` hook to intercept commands before it has a chance to fail and create a temporary function. I use a variant of this with, the nmh mailer for showing e-mail messages by number.

Answer (score 1):

With bash, you can use the `command_not_found_handle` function.

Take care that **a)** some distros are already using it to provide their "install *foobar* if you want to use the *foo* command" feature, and **b)** it will not override external commands, as shell functions do.

Also notice that `\d` is not supported by the regex dialect used by bash with the `=~` operator (which, btw is the only use of regexes in bash).

```
2digits(){
    echo "$1_or_smth"
}
command_not_found_handle(){
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then 2digits "$@"
    else printf >&2 '%s: command not found\n' "$1"; return 127 
    fi
}
```

then

```
$ 33
33_or_smth
$ 444
444: command not found
```

---

The same thing works in zsh with the `command_not_found_handler` function (notice the name difference -- there is an extra "r" in zsh).

While you could simulate zsh's `preexec` with a `DEBUG` trap in bash, you won't be able to do the trick from the other answer, since bash doesn't allow function names which contain only digits.